# iOS 8 GameCenter Not Working on Device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, game-center

I have a GameCenter enabled app which has been setup correctly with iTunes Connect, it works perfectly on the simulator, but when trying on the iPhone 6 it doesn't work.

After doing some debugging I discovered that, even though I'm not signed into GameCenter and Sandbox more is enabled in settings, that the viewController in the authenticationHandler is nil.

Is this a common issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having spent a bit of time - I did end up "answering" this a while ago (forgot I'd posted a question here).

I don't fully understand what happened - but around the time that the 8.1 beta came out - I installed that on my phone (which wiped it, annoyingly) but I figured every cloud has a silver lining and tried it again and it seemed to work straight away.

So although its not a direct answer to the question it did fix it. My advice though - Make a backup of your phone before restoring if you ever get this issue.